# Am I correct with this line of reasoning? (would/would have)

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

1. I thought you *would* come.

   Here, I was thinking that you would come in the future, this sentence shows futurity in the past.
2. I thought you *would have* come.

   But here, I thought that you already came with the added meaning of "willingness" that's why I
   used "would have". Here I could have used "had come" but this would not have conveyed the added
   meaning of "willingness".

Am I right with this line of reasoning or not? Please explain if I'm wrong.

Comment: What’s the context?  These could mean several very different things.

Comment: Same question asked on ELL [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297718/am-i-correct-with-this-line-of-reasoning-would-would-have)

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right with this line of reasoning or not?

No. It is far more complicated and you **must** provide context.

A: You weren't at my party on Saturday: I thought you would come.

B: Sorry, I was ill.

A: I'm having another party next Saturday: I thought you would (=might) come.

B: That's good of you. I will try to be there.

A: Last month, some of us met at a pub. I thought you would have been there, too.

B: I was in Australia.

A: When you were in Australia, did you watch the cricket?

B: No. It was in Perth, and I went to Canberra - I would have been too late anyway - it had already ended.

Here are some other examples:

1   I wish he would do what I asked.    Regret about somebody's behaviour

2   Would you follow me, please?.   Polite request

3   He said he would do it tomorrow.    Reported speech

4   I'd rather you didn't do that.  Expressing a preference about an action

5   And every day he would go to work by bicycle.   Past habit

6   Well, he would say that, wouldn't he?   Commenting on somebody's typical behaviour

7   Would you tell me the answer?   Indirect question

8   Would you like to go to the cinema? Polite offer

9   I'd imagine we would arrive at about six .  Softening an opinion you are not sure about

10  He wouldn't do what I asked.    Refusal in the past

11  One day he would return to this university as a professor.  Future in the past

12  If he had known this he would never have asked her. Third conditional

There are a similar number of meanings for "would have verbed".

Comment: Last month, some of us met at a pub. I thought you would have been there, too. In this sentence how would you modify it if I wanted to convey that at the time of "thinking" at the pub I was expecting him too see a few minutes later at the pub. Would I say " I thought you "would" be there too"

Comment: You can only say this **after** the meeting - not at the time of the meeting. As you leave, you say "I though he would be here." The example becomes reported speech:  I thought [that] you would have been there, too.

Comment: look at this sentence- The Pandemic might just be the best thing that could have happened to your business! Why did they use "could have" when pandemic actually happened in reality. I thought "could have", "would have" constructions are used for imagined actions in the past that in reality did not happen.